# How Can I Unjoin Meshes?

Tags: mesh

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join meshes, but now I want to take them apart. Is there a simple way?

Comment: Like `P` *> By Selection*?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you can easily select the vertices that you want to separate, then in edit mode press <kbd>P</kbd> *> By Selection*. You may also be able to use the *By Material* if the materials are different or *By Loose Parts* if the objects are not connected.

**By Selection:**

[image: By Selection]

**By Materials:**

[image: By Materials]

**By Loose Parts:**

[image: By Loose Parts]

Comment: But is there any other way?

Comment: No. What exactly do you need you separate?

Comment: Well, when I tried to join objects, the origins were at different points, so I couldn't animate it.

Comment: When you join two objects, then whichever is active will retain its origin, and the other mesh will be joined to that mesh. I still don't get exactly what your issue is. Could you update your question?

Comment: Oh well. The "P" thing worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the 3D window, select the object that has an origin in the wrong place. Choose `Object -> Transform... -> Origin to Geometry` and it will move the origin to the weighted center of the mesh.

Comment: pressing P doesnt do anything for me

Comment: @csharpnewbie Were you in edit mode?