# 2 objects use the same mesh; how to separate?

Tags: modeling

I don't know how I ended up with 2 objects that share the same mesh (Cube.143) in my bench model; I want to have a unique mesh for each. Suggestions welcome. thanks

ps: I can't find any apparent linkage between the two objects.

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/how-to-make-multi-user-objects-single-user

Comment: You've probably joinded two meshes (pressed Ctrl+J). Separate them (P) : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41205/how-can-i-unjoin-meshes

Comment: I think it was a case of a linked object.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the object data section of the properties you'll see a number indicating the number of objects that share the same mesh. If you click on it it will make the object it's own different mesh.

[image]

Comment: perfect. that was it.