# objects not showing up in outliner

Tags: 3d-view, outliner

It's probably a problem of settings but I cannot figure out what I did.
Each time I add a new object in my scene, it shows up on the scene and it is rendered but it doesn't show up on the outliner list.
Which is a bit annoying, I like to keep things tidy.
If I reset to factory setting, and duplicate the starting cube, I finally have two cubes in my outliner. But even after reseting the setting, the problem is still here when loading my original scene.
Any hints?

Edit:
I added a screenshot, in the outliner menu, only the cylinder is displayed.

[image: outliner only show cylinder]

Comment: Loading factory defaults won't influence on other files if you haven't saved startup file with `Ctrl`+`U`. But before doing that, backup your original startup file (maybe problem fixes easily). Can you provide some screenshots of the problem in the Outliner ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only one object in this scene, and all these shapes are part of that same object. You probably added each new mesh in Edit Mode, instead of Object Mode.

When you add a new mesh primitive while in edit mode, the new primitive is added into the same object you are in the process of editing.

Since the name of the object is "Cylinder", I assume you created the cylinder first, then added the other shapes while editing the cylinder.

You can see that this has happened since all 3 meshes are editable when you are in edit mode. Normally, when meshes are separated into different objects, you can only edit one at a time:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, when adding new object in Object mode, they appear in the tree structure. Any way to reverse it, to separate my objects? Edit: fount it, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: In edit mode, select all (Shortcut: "A"), then press "P" (separate) --> By Loose Parts.

Comment: See this link for a detailed explanation of how to separate meshes: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41205/how-can-i-unjoin-meshes

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Make sure [All Scenes] is selected and no search text is present in the outliner, in the header.

There are multiple reasons to consider when an object is not [immediately visible] or [doesnt show up] in the outliner.  If one object is the parent of other child objects, then the parent may be visible with icons indicating children are subordinate.  Yet you may not see the names of the children.  By clicking the [+ or -] you will see more or less.  This is similar to file folder views on your computer OS.  This can be used as a feature. You have the control to view what you want to view.

Expanded view showing parent child hierarchy follows

[image]

If you have searched via text in the outliner such as "cube" and forgotten you searched you may have limited your view.   Clear any search text.

Search Text example follows.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but different problem:

You also can have objects that just haven't been assigned to a collection yet.

In Object Mode: select objects -> press M -> move to collection

Now it will show in the outliner.